How to move text to the top next to the image
The red line should be place in the blue line
Just like this
I dont know how to fix this with the "float" method , because when i read lots of tutorials they said i have to use the float method but when i use the float method , it jumps to the bottom of the image and idk how to fix this. U can use other methods
Here's the code:
HTML:


.lastpart{
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.lastpart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item-cer {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.886);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;

}

.certify{
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.spec{
  border-right: 1px solid #d6c08d;
}
.s{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.giaikk{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  float: right;
  
}
.provekk{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;

}
<div class="lastpart">
  
  <div class="grid-item-cer spec">
    <h3 class="certify">Chứng Chỉ - Giải Thưởng</h3>
    <img src="s.jpg" class="s"
    width="150px"
    height="200px"
    >
    <h5 class="giaikk">ĐẠT GIẢI KHUYẾN KHÍCH KHỐI 7 TOÀN QUỐC - IOE</h5>
    <p class="provekk">-Chứng chỉ được cấp bỏi Internet Olympiads of English</p>





  </div>




This can be solved with float, but I would heavily recommend against it. I think you have probably been misled by reading out of date information. You should look into "flexbox" CSS for situations like this. Once you know how to use flexbox, solving layout problems like this becomes extremely simple! Or potentially if you still need help, maybe re-post your question as "How can I place two sets of elements next to each other using flexbox?"

I should add, though, to point you in the right direction in both cases: you need to wrap your <h5> and <p> inside another element, eg. a <div>. If you have this layout: <div><h5></h5><p></p></div> then you just need to position the <div> where you want it to be (eg. with float or flexbox) and then all of the elements inside it will move together.

As you want text alongside the image it just depends on whether you want it to float around the image if there is too much of it to stay on pthe right, in which case float is the answer, or whether you want to maintain two columns in which case flex or grid, with some html restructuring, could be the answer.
